# I want select records that have same value and one user of joomla add it in database table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

My db picture

[http://www.m-iau.ac.ir/db.jpg http://www.m-iau.ac.ir/db.jpg](http://www.m-iau.ac.ir/db.jpg)

this is my php code

```
$user   = JFactory::getUser();
$db   = JFactory::getDbo();
$userId  = $user->get('email');
// Is the user logged in?
if ($userId) {
  // Grab the value from the database.
  $db->setQuery("SELECT `value` FROM `#__facileforms_subrecords` WHERE `value` like '09%'   GROUP BY `record` HAVING `record`='".$userId."'");
  return $db->loadResult();
}
```

In table any user add have same record(Column), I want display user records only in this table

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to get all rows belonging to the same user (e.g. record = 1)? Is the content of the record column the userId? Then maybe change $user->get('email') to $user->get('id')...

Comment: i want to get all rows belonging to the same user

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all rows belonging to the current user, get the user ID first:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->id; // or $user->get('id');
```

Then create the query:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('value'))
->from($db->quoteName('#__facileforms_subrecords'))
->where($db->quoteName('record')."=".$db->quote($id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadRowList(); // loadObjectList() or whatever you need
```

Then you'll get all values belonging to the current user.

Comment: We have not in this table id (user id). we have email, name and user name. i test the cods by email but no display any thing!

Comment: that is why you are getting the id from the current user, this is what $user->get('id') does. I understand the record column corresponds to the id? Thus, just get the ID as I wrote and compare it to the record column.

Comment: I test but no display any thing!